# Jquery animation only shows when mouse is moving.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have no idea why this happens and I've already googled it. I've made a slideshow that scrolls the leftmost element outside of screen then appends it to the end of the container. That function itself seems to work as expected. However the animation only shows when I'm moving my mouse so something is wrong here.

Any idea of what?

Without moving mouse: https://gyazo.com/78048123b10e1d2683b102419761c0ef
When moving mouse:  https://gyazo.com/f10bf8a10bc119840bd6b5b1168e79db

Html:

```
<section class="photo-grid-slideshow">
        <div class="photo-crop">
            <h3>I wanna
                <div class="xs-spacer"></div>
                <a class="med-btn btn-white">Read more</a>
            </h3>
            <div class="photo-grid-container" style="background-image: url('Images and videos/odesza1.jpg');"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="photo-crop">
            <h3>Dance
                <div class="xs-spacer"></div>
                <a class="med-btn btn-white">Read more</a>
            </h3>
            <div class="photo-grid-container" style="background-image: url('Images and videos/odesza3.jpg');"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="photo-crop">
            <h3>With you
                <div class="xs-spacer"></div>
                <a class="med-btn btn-white">Read more</a>
            </h3>
            <div class="photo-grid-container" style="background-image: url('Images and videos/odesza2.png');"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Css:

```
.photo-crop {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    text-align: left;
}

.photo-grid-slideshow {
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background: black;
    padding: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #444;
}
```

Javascript:

```
 $(function () {
     var timer = setInterval(function() {
        $(".photo-grid-slideshow .photo-crop:first-child").animate({marginLeft: '-=33vw'}, 1000, "linear", function() {
            $(this).css("margin-left", 0).appendTo('.photo-grid-slideshow');
        });
    }, 1000);
 });
```

I'm very thankful if ýou can help me get this to work. :)

Comment: Do you need [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Lojuhpbx/)

Comment: I think so since it first sets the margin negative and then needs to reset it before moving it to the right

Comment: @Mitch How could it be though? I didn't have this problem with the exact same animation but on the container. No problem there. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work at least. The problem was that the .photo-crop class had transition: **ALL** on it. Because of that it couldn't animate it in jquery. Silly mistake, but for me it wasn't apparent.

Hope this can help someone else in the future!